# Как отправить файл с помощью axios методом post чтобы сохранить на сервере VK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Мне нужно отправить файл формата **.txt**

Код:

```
let text = "File: File"
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('tempfiles/temp.txt', text, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
}); // Сохраняю файл temp.txt в папке tempfiles

vk.api.docs.getMessagesUploadServer({type: `doc`, peer_id: message.peerId}) 
.then(res => { //Получаю ссылку для post запроса на сервер

    let link = res.upload_url
    var formData = new FormData(); // ну это понятно
    formData.set("file", "./tempfiles/temp.txt") // подозрение на эту часть
    axios.post(link, formData, { 
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        },
    }).then(function (response) {
        console.log(response.data)
    }) // отправил запрос в формате, который нужен для вк (multipart/form-data)
})
```

Получаю ошибку:

```
{
error: 'ERR_UPLOAD_BAD_SIGNATURE',
bwact: 'add_doc_new',
server: 236331,
_sig: '533dd4090a031c8f03791ff7571ff741'
}
```

Comment: попробуйте fs.writeFileSync