# Как исправить ошибку 404 при переходе на файл в VK?

Tags: javascript, node.js, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Я загружаю файл temp.txt в вк и отправляю его:

```
bot.hear(/^[!/.](?:genf)/i, async (message) => {
let text = "File: File"
var fs = require('fs');
fs.writeFile('tempfiles/temp.txt', text, (err) => {
    if (err) throw err;
});
await vk.upload.messageDocument({
    peer_id: message.peerId,
    source: {
        value: "C:ПУТЬ\\tempfiles\\temp.txt",
        filename: "test.txt",
        contentType: "text"
    }
}).then(response => {
    console.log(response)
    message.send("123", {attachment: response})
})
});
```

Все вроде впорядке, получаю в консоль:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Получаю сообщение:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Перехожу по txt файлу и получаю:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я думаю что ошибка где то в коде vk.upload.messageDocument в source, хотя путь указан верно.

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1554262/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb-%d1%81-%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bc%d0%be%d1%89%d1%8c%d1%8e-axios-%d0%bc%d0%b5%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%bc-post-%d1%87%d1%82%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d1%81%d0%be%d1%85%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%bd%d0%b0-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5-vk#comment2799480_1554262

Comment: Как мне это юзать по твоему

Comment: вместо writeFile

Comment: Все равно ошибка бро.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка на стороне VK, в беседы созданные группой возникает такая ошибка. Решения просто нет.